# Angular 2: Ts: Nested functions

Tags: javascript, angular, types

I'm working on a function and can someone give advice on how to specify a function that is out side a function?
Inside the if statment I would like to call the otherfunction().

```
@Injectable()
export class menuService {
    constructor (){}
    testing(){ console.log('something')}
    loadwidget(){


           // not able to call this function
           this.testing()

    }
}
```

Error that i get is **"this.testing is not a function"**

```
ERROR TypeError: this.testing is not a function
    at Object.menuService.loadwidget (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:755:14)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (ng:///AppModule/tbuttonsComponent.ngfactory.js:36:41)
    at handleEvent (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:13146:138)
    at callWithDebugContext (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:14354:42)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:13942:12)
    at dispatchEvent (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:10121:21)
    at http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:10711:38
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/XCHsu19UhR9wWxz4VLOx?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly how you're supposed to access other methods within a class, off of the `this` keyword. If you're using your class above exactly as it's written out, then the issue is that `variableName` isn't defined anywhere within `customfunction()` so it errors out. The `console.log()` statement in `otherfunction()` never gets a chance to run because of that.

**Edit:** I took a look at the Plunker you added in, it turns out it's a scoping issue. I updated the `menuService` class, using arrow functions to implicitly bind `this` to `menuService`, and the third button started working as expected:

```
export class menuService {
  constructor (){
    // I moved this into the constructor and updated loadingwidget below
    this.menu = [{
      id: 1,
      loadingwidget: () => { this.loadwidget(); },
    }];
  }

  testing(){ 
    console.log('something');
    alert('something');
  }

  loadwidget(){
    this.testing();
  }
}
```

Here's a working version of your Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/sF08cccRb2b0xkfTspVV?p=preview

Comment: Can it because it is an injectable?

Comment: @ChrisTarasovs Take a look at my edit, it's not an @injectable issue, it's an issue with `this` not being bound to `menuService`.

Answer (score 0):

How you have defined should work. If `otherfunction()` isn't called check you if statement, maybe the comparison doesn't return what you expect.

Please look at this plunker example: https://plnkr.co/edit/4MWYDdeS5cCTDHI64HO2?p=preview

Comment: I have updated exactly the way I have it , I am getting that it is not a function but I am calling it correctly.

Comment: I have updated the plunker example which is also working with your code. Would you compare with your code? Please also look where you call loadwidget().

Comment: here  is closer to what I have code wise: https://plnkr.co/edit/XCHsu19UhR9wWxz4VLOx?p=preview

Comment: so I am loading the menu from a object and than onclick I load a function that is in defined in the object and in that function there is a function that I would like to call

Comment: You try to give a method as parameter in an object. This is how I would do in JavaScript but in Typescript I would use the benefits of classes. Instead of using an array in menuService, create an array of menuServices in App.ts and use this for your widgets. Because each menuService object has his own params. example plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/Lrx37LFTitDLXETcont9?p=preview. If you want to use html objects with his own logic behind I would recommend to create directives: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/recursive-treeview-in-angular-2.0

Answer (score 0):

This is not because of Injectable and you don't need Injectable also as you are not injecting anything into the service. So you can omit that. But I could see there are few issue in the code like this one,

```
 menu = [
      {
        id = 1,
        loadingwidget: this.loadwidget
      }
    ]
```

where it should be

```
menu = [
      {
        id:1,
        loadingwidget: this.loadwidget
      }
    ]
```

and it was not compiled properly. It works just fine.